# Pre-90s anime with a red-haired man in an outer space war shot at the ending

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember as a child watching an anime movie on tape between 89-91 when I was 7-9 years old. I think it was set in outer space and there was some kind of war (I remember that there were a couple of war scenes with spaceships).

I only remember two characters, a red haired man (short spiky/bushy hair) and a white/silvery haired man (long straight with or without bangs) that were friends. I think the red haired man was a leader of some sort. I mostly remember the ending. The two men were standing in a cave of some sort with a cliff. The ground was orange/brown. The white haired man had a gun, but I can't remember if he was was aiming it on the red haired man or if it was hidden. They stood a distance from each other and spoke for a while, then the red haired man turned his back on the white haired man and started to walk away. The white haired man then shot him in the back and he fell down the cliff. I then remember the white haired man later sitting in a conference room briefing his superiors/colleagues and looking very sad.

I just remember being so shocked by the ending. I thought that the red haired man was the hero and I couldn't believe that he got killed. Since I didn't really understand the language I might have gotten the story wrong. He might have been the villain. The thing is that I'm from Iraq but raised in Sweden. We went back to Iraq between 89-91 where I saw the movie. I only spoke Swedish at the time so I don't know if the movie was in English or dubbed to Arabic. The funny thing is that it was my older brother's tape, but he has no recollection of seeing that movie.

Comment: Did it seem like it was the end of a series (e.g, were you dropped into the middle of things at the start), or did it seem self-contained? About how long was it?

Comment: I wish i could remember. I just remember that the movie was quite long. Its just the ending that stuck with me.

Comment: I think I remember something. I have a vague recollection of a female character. I think she might have been involved with the red haired man in some way. She might also have been involved in his shooting. Dont remember if she might have tried to save him or if she might have been the white haired mans superior in some way. Hope I'm remembering correctly

Comment: Does the white hair guy look like Zechs Merquise at all?

Comment: Can you describe what you remember about the war? Did they use guns, lasers, robots? Did the ships look like standard SciFi ships, or like sail boats, trains, or submarines in space?

Comment: It could be Zechs, but I remember him having a rounder chin and more of his face showing. Dont remember that well but he might have been wearing something red. What I remember from the war scences is that they faught in single-pilot ships (traditional anime spaceships) and used either lasers or guns.

Comment: Could it be Macross or Space Battleship Yamato? Could the white haired guy have been a woman? Check this link for familiar images: [Yamato](http://www.starblazers.com/home.php)

Answer (score 3):

This sounds vaguely like [the Harlock series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Harlock). It was translated many different languages and some films have scenes that are similar to the ones you describe, although they aren't the major plot of any of the films.

[image: An image of a giant red-haired man in a large cape, standing in space.]

Comment: Thanks I'll look it up. Although I dont remember him beeing a pirate and having a scar or an eyepatch. I also remember him having more spiky hair

Comment: @Sarah, there are many many sub-plots and major characters it could be from the series. If the overall style looks right, it is likely this. The animator has a very distinctive style.

Comment: I immediately thought of Harlock/Galaxy Express 999/Emeraldas, but none of the movies have a straight-haired blonde guy.

Comment: @GorchestopherH but many have straight haired women that can be misremembered as guys. I mean. Look at Harlock there. Not exactly manly looking.

Comment: @DampeS8N Yeah, I had that thought too. The only scenes like the one described are from Gundam, but the only thing that fits with the Spacecraft description are items from Yamato.